# How do I fix mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 2, current count = 3.

But I don't know enough about SQL Server to stop the error.

Here is my `DROP PROCEDURE` command:

```
--Specify database in which to uninstall procedure
USE SalesLogix_Dev
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'usp_matt_db_tasks')
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE usp_matt_db_tasks
GO
```

And here is the `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
--Specify database in which to install procedure
USE SalesLogix_Dev
GO

--Drop existing objects in order to guanrantee error-free install
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'usp_matt_db_tasks')
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE usp_matt_db_tasks
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE usp_matt_db_tasks
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] (
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    MODIFYUSER,
    MODIFYDATE,
    FIRSTNAME,
    ACCOUNTMANAGERID,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    COMPANY,
    COMPANY_UC,
    EMAIL,
    DONOTSOLICIT,
    ISPRIMARY,
    LEADSOURCEID,
    SECCODEID,
    STATUS,
    LASTNAME,
    LASTNAME_UC,
    INDUSTRY,
    NOTES,
    HOMEPHONE) 
SELECT 
       ,'something'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'something'    
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,replace(firstname, '"', '')
       ,'something'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,replace(company, '"', '')
       ,replace(UPPER(company), '"', '')
       ,replace(email, '"', '')
       ,'1'
       ,'T'
       ,''
       ,'SYST00000001'
       ,'New'
       ,replace(lastname, '"', '')
       ,replace(UPPER(lastname), '"', '')
       ,replace(department, '"', '')
       ,replace(comments, '"', '')
       ,replace(phone, '"', '')

  FROM [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[CSVTemp]

update  [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] set LEAD_ADDRESSID = 'Q' + LEADID where DONOTSOLICIT = 1

INSERT INTO [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD_ADDRESS] (
    LEAD_ADDRESSID,
    LEADID,
    CREATEUSER,
    CREATEDATE,
    MODIFYUSER,
    MODIFYDATE,
    ISMAILING,
    ISPRIMARY) 
SELECT 
      LEAD_ADDRESSID
     ,LEADID
     ,'something'
     ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     ,'something'      
     ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     ,'T'
     ,'T'

  FROM [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] where DONOTSOLICIT = 1

  update  [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] set DONOTSOLICIT = 0 where DONOTSOLICIT = 1
  DROP TABLE [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[CSVTemp]
  ROLLBACK  TRANSACTION
COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

And finally I execute as follows:

```
USE SalesLogix_Dev
GO

EXEC usp_matt_db_tasks;
```

Comment: Why do you have a `ROLLBACK` followed immediately by a `COMMIT`? Are you trying to commit or roll back? I also guess this procedure has more instances of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (or it is called by another procedure that has its own transaction context). I much prefer a complete question to a shortened question that is missing vital information. Can you show us the whole procedure please?

Comment: i added the rollback because I thought it would fix the issue

Comment: is there a way to delete every instance of this procedure

Comment: You have multiple instances of the procedure? This is probably because you're not using the dbo. prefix. Instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE usp_whatever` always, always, always use `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_whatever`... and reference it that way when you're calling it, too. Anyway, show us the WHOLE procedure... the answer brain posted shows why it's not very helpful to only post selected parts of the procedure.

Comment: Ok i will show the whole thing one sec

Comment: I suspect there is more info you're not telling us. Are you calling this stored procedure from another procedure, or from a session where you've already started transactions? What does `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;` yield in the current window? Are you 100% positive you are calling the right instance of `usp_matt_db_tasks`? Or is it possible that there are multiple copies under different schemas, and you're looking at the wrong one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3458/discussion-between-alex-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: It just started working and not sure what happen....thanks again @aaron

Comment: First, you should use try catch block when using transactions.  What you need is to have two paths, one for the commit if everything goes well and one for the rollback.

Comment: @HLGEM I considered adding `TRY`/`CATCH` to my answer but I thought it better to tackle one issue at a time. :-)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, that's why I made it a comment, so he would know to look at how to do that but not to confuse it with this problem.

Comment: @HLGEM right I made a similar comment at the end of my answer. I wasn't questioning whether or not you should bring it up too, just making an excuse for why I did not add error handling to the procedure in my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To drop all the procedures with the name `usp_matt_db_tasks` you can run this query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'DROP PROCEDURE ' 
    + SCHEMA_ID(name) + '.'
    + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
    FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'usp_matt_db_tasks';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You should rollback any transactions that are currently active, close your current window, then create procedure in a new query window:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_matt_db_tasks
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] 
    (
      CREATEUSER,
      ...
      HOMEPHONE
    ) 
    SELECT 
          ,'something'
          ...
          ,replace(phone, '"', '')
    FROM [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[CSVTemp];

    UPDATE [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] 
      SET LEAD_ADDRESSID = 'Q' + LEADID 
      WHERE DONOTSOLICIT = 1;

    INSERT INTO [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD_ADDRESS] 
    (
      LEAD_ADDRESSID,
              ...
      ISPRIMARY
    ) 
    SELECT 
      LEAD_ADDRESSID
              ,...
      ,'T'
    FROM [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD]
    WHERE DONOTSOLICIT = 1;

    UPDATE [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[LEAD] 
      SET DONOTSOLICIT = 0 
      WHERE DONOTSOLICIT = 1;

    DROP TABLE [SalesLogix_Dev].[sysdba].[CSVTemp];

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Now when you call this procedure you should always use `EXEC dbo.usp_matt_db_tasks;` and you should probably consider adding some error handling so that you can properly rollback the transaction in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're rolling back the transaction, then trying to commit.

Both should end a "begin transaction".

Comment: what do you mean ...i just added the rollback but the error was like this before the rollback